# Guide on implementing ads is very vague, what is meant to put in?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I've been following [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) tutorial on Adding ads to an application. The part that says:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
```

is incredible frustrating.

I understand that `ADMOB_APP_ID` is this `ca-app-pub-numbers~numbers` but do you keep the square brackets in or not? Also what is `APPLICATION_ID`? I've tried using the admob app id, the `applicationID` under `defaultconfig`, even leaving it as `APPLICATIONID` but nothing is working

Here's what my current xml file attempt looks like:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.Application_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-numbers~numbers"/>
```

Comment: Follow this answer [View this answer for clear undertanding admob ads implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294162/cannot-import-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-ads17-1-1/53443104#53443104)

Comment: That upper case `APPLICATION_ID` is really sucks for misunderstanding people to think of what should we put...

Comment: keep ->  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" _as it is. change  --> android:value="Your ad-mob ad id"

Answer (score 2):

it should look alike this (the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

where the `ADMOB_APP_ID` is the ID obtained from the Firebase console.

hint: you need to scroll down the menu to the left; it's the last item there.

Comment: So you leave `android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"  as ` android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"` without changing anything and use this: https://imgur.com/a/ExNf46M for the ADMOB_APP_ID

Comment: Realised what I did wrong! I had "Aplication_ID" instead of "APPLICATION_ID" in my actual app

Comment: @L.F such `public final static` constant names are always uppercase in Java.