# NoSuchMethodException when trying to launch my app from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android programming and can't launch my app installed from Android studio. I've installed my app to my phone via USB. Everything went fine before I launched. Then it crashes and stop without displaying any error. So I've tried on another phone sending my app from my phone. They can't even install it.

Below is my log cat when I launch my app.

```
2019-01-18 21:59:59.218 28416-28416/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-01-18 21:59:59.230 28416-28416/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
2019-01-18 21:59:59.240 28416-28416/? W/ReflectionUtils: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
    at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
    at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
    at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
    at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
    at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
    at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6366)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
2019-01-18 21:59:59.275 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.gpchat.ppk-1/lib/arm64
2019-01-18 21:59:59.373 28416-28435/com.gpchat.ppk W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2019-01-18 21:59:59.389 28416-28437/com.gpchat.ppk W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2019-01-18 21:59:59.393 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2019-01-18 21:59:59.394 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2019-01-18 21:59:59.396 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-01-18 21:59:59.397 28416-28437/com.gpchat.ppk I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
2019-01-18 21:59:59.397 28416-28437/com.gpchat.ppk I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation

--------- beginning of crash
2019-01-18 21:59:59.397 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gpchat.ppk, PID: 28416
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: https://goo. gl/fQ2neu to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: https://goo. gl/h17b6x.                           *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5589)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5528)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1625)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6383)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: https://goo. gl/fQ2neu to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: https://goo. gl/h17b6x.                           *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6110)
        ... 10 more
2019-01-18 21:59:59.426 28416-28439/com.gpchat.ppk I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 14710
2019-01-18 21:59:59.426 28416-28439/com.gpchat.ppk I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2019-01-18 21:59:59.427 28416-28439/com.gpchat.ppk I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
  adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.my.talker.ppk
2019-01-18 21:59:59.454 28416-28416/com.gpchat.ppk I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28416 SIG: 9
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest.xml to the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786963/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-android-gms-ads-mobileadsinitprovider-java-la)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: https://goo. gl/fQ2neu to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: https://goo. gl/h17b6x.                           *
******************************************************************************
```

This happened due to updated AdMob SDK. Now you need to add appID in your manifest file.

```
<application> . . . 
      <meta-data 
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
           android:value="ca-app-pub-################~##########"/>
</application>
```

You can get appID from here -->Google addmob -->Select app --> App Settings --> App ID.

Also, Try adding this dependency to your gradle build file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
```