# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main crash when app start

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, admob

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dslr.camera.pixol, PID: 8021
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

---

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxw.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:27)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        ... 10 more
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8021 SIG: 9
Process 8021 terminated.

```
compileSdkVersion 29
flavorDimensions "default"
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    multiDexEnabled true
```

i can't understand where is the problem, compile is ok and when i try to run the app i get crash and app exit. what i can do, please help me
Thanks

Comment: You are not  properly defined your admob app id or you put wrong app id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instructions in the log to add your app id in your AndroidManifest.xml? I noticed that the second link does not seem to work; you may have to update to the latest google-mobile-ads sdk (18.3.0).

You can find the AndroidManifest app id setup guide [here](https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest) following the first link.

Ref: [Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786963/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-android-gms-ads-mobileadsinitprovider-java-la)

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the Admob in your application level or in your activity so you need to add this line after  onCreate.

```
String AdmobID ="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";    
MobileAds.initialize(this, AdmobID);
```

and don't forget to replace the AdmobId with yours.