# My app immanently crashes after I open it. Just updated it after 2 years and with new unity updates (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, logcat

I've just finished updating my app, I built the final version ready to be published and I noticed I had a new package name. I overrode the name with the previous name. Now when i open the app. it just crashes immanently. I have LONG logcat here. I have spent about 10 hours looking for a solution and now looking for anyone who has had the same problem. I'm not too good at looking through logcats and understanding what it means.

```
03-08 14:03:59.586 7608:7608 I/AppStartUtils]
isUserUnlocked : true, isUserQuiet : false

[03-08 14:03:59.586 7608:7608 W/AppStartUtils]
sendActiveLaunchBroadcast() v.hasOnClickListeners() : true, iconInfo : AppInfo(id=222 type=APP hidden=0 container=all_apps screen=3 rank=1 user=UserHandle{0} title=TickTock SoundBoard - Popular TikTok Sounds componentName=ComponentInfo{com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} screenType=0)

[03-08 14:03:59.587 8404:8404 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - TABoost/8404@13, type = 1090523139

[03-08 14:03:59.587 7608:7608 I/FastBitmapDrawable]
animatePress : true  immediate : false invalidate : true

[03-08 14:03:59.587 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]releaseLocked(): Released ID : 35427166

[03-08 14:03:59.587 1166:7322 I/Pageboost]
start alp : com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.587 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 35427166  [8404 / 13]    HINT :      list : [TABoost / 30] [TIMEOUT / 1500] 

[03-08 14:03:59.587 1166:7322 D/ActivityTaskManager]
Checking for the Active launch isPkgEverLaunched :true, isPkgStopped : false, isDataCleared :false, isAutoRunBlocked : false

[03-08 14:03:59.588 1166:7345 I/Pageboost]
alp for : com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard , 0

[03-08 14:03:59.588 1166:7322 W/ContextImpl]
Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:1056 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService$ActiveLaunchReceiver.onReceive:1068 android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args:1666 android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run:2 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 

[03-08 14:03:59.588 8020:2887 E/pageboostd]
alp start : app comShadowZTickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.589 8020:2887 E/pageboostd]
comShadowZTickTockSoundBoard, amt 6300728 scnt 3 fcnt 0

[03-08 14:03:59.589 1166:7322 E/ActivityTaskManager]
TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch

[03-08 14:03:59.589 8020:2887 E/pageboostd]
comShadowZTickTockSoundBoard, amt 0 scnt 3 fcnt 0

[03-08 14:03:59.589 8020:2887 E/pageboostd]
alp end : app comShadowZTickTockSoundBoard data_amount 6300728

[03-08 14:03:59.589 1166:7322 D/ActivityTaskManager]
starting Active launch

[03-08 14:03:59.590 1166:1521 D/StorageManagerService]
getExternalStorageMountMode: uid=10295 packageName=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.590 1166:1521 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.590 1166:1521 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 135754954; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.591 1166:1539 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.598 2847:2847 I/libc]
SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0

[03-08 14:03:59.602 791:791 I/zygote]
Priority USAP Pool refill. New USAPs: 1

[03-08 14:03:59.602 1166:1539 I/ActivityManager]
Start proc 2847:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/u0a295 for activelaunch {com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}

[03-08 14:03:59.604 7608:7608 W/StatusBarController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent return false by intercept 

[03-08 14:03:59.604 7608:7608 W/BaseDragLayer]
findActiveController return false mTouchDispatchState = 9

[03-08 14:03:59.608 791:791 D/Zygote]
Forked child process 2890

[03-08 14:03:59.609 2847:2847 E/kTockSoundBoar]
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.

[03-08 14:03:59.612 2847:2847 D/ActivityThread]
setConscryptValidator

[03-08 14:03:59.612 2847:2847 D/ActivityThread]
setConscryptValidator - put

[03-08 14:03:59.614 1166:7430 I/ActivityManager]
DSS OFF for com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.616 1166:7430 D/ActivityManager]
attachApplicationLocked() app=ProcessRecord{1b4e955 2847:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/u0a295} app.isolatedEntryPoint=null instr2=null

[03-08 14:03:59.619 2847:2847 D/ActivityThread]
handleBindApplication()++ app=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.622 2847:2847 D/ApplicationLoaders]
Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar

[03-08 14:03:59.623 2847:2847 I/kTockSoundBoar]
The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.

[03-08 14:03:59.632 2847:2847 D/LoadedApk]
LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@6969dac appContext.mOpPackageName=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard appContext.mBasePackageName=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@133ba75

[03-08 14:03:59.632 2847:2847 D/NetworkSecurityConfig]
No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

[03-08 14:03:59.633 2847:2847 D/NetworkSecurityConfig]
No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

[03-08 14:03:59.634 2847:2847 D/AndroidRuntime]
Shutting down VM

[03-08 14:03:59.635 2847:2847 E/AndroidRuntime]
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, PID: 2847
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

[03-08 14:03:59.637 1166:7430 D/Debug]
low && ship && 3rd party app crash, so skip dump

[03-08 14:03:59.637 1166:7430 W/ActivityManager]
crash : com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard,10295

[03-08 14:03:59.637 1166:7430 W/ContextImpl]
Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:579 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:443 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:12392 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash:12327 

[03-08 14:03:59.637 7608:7608 W/StatusBarController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent return false by intercept 

[03-08 14:03:59.637 7608:7608 W/BaseDragLayer]
findActiveController return false mTouchDispatchState = 9

[03-08 14:03:59.640 2847:2847 I/Process]
Sending signal. PID: 2847 SIG: 9

[03-08 14:03:59.646 8404:8404 I/SDHMS:PowerAnomaly:GATHERERAPPERROR]
update AppError : uid=10295, pkg=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, errorType=crash

[03-08 14:03:59.649 1166:9322 I/ActivityManager]
Process com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard (pid 2847) has died: picked CEM (245,2285)

[03-08 14:03:59.650 8404:8404 I/SDHMS:PowerAnomaly:ANALYZERAPPERROR]
analyze app error : uid=10295, pkg=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, appErrorCount=7

[03-08 14:03:59.654 791:791 I/Zygote]
Process 2847 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)

[03-08 14:03:59.654 1136:2040 I/CameraService]
UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10295 disabled=0

[03-08 14:03:59.654 7608:7608 W/StatusBarController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent return false by intercept 

[03-08 14:03:59.654 7608:7608 W/BaseDragLayer]
findActiveController return false mTouchDispatchState = 9

[03-08 14:03:59.656 1166:1541 I/libprocessgroup]
Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10295 pid 2847 in 6ms

[03-08 14:03:59.671 7608:7608 W/StatusBarController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent return false by intercept 

[03-08 14:03:59.671 7608:7608 W/BaseDragLayer]
findActiveController return false mTouchDispatchState = 9

[03-08 14:03:59.671 864:2864 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]removeResource(): [CPUMinFreq] RemoveResource Request ID : 721836

[03-08 14:03:59.672 864:2864 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]releaseLocked(): Released ID : 721836

[03-08 14:03:59.683 1166:2103 D/InputReader]
Btn_touch(7): value=0 when=41675.300783

[03-08 14:03:59.683 1166:2103 I/InputReader]
Touch event's action is 0x1 (id=5, t=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=41675.300783

[03-08 14:03:59.683 1166:2102 I/InputDispatcher]
Delivering touch to (7608): action: 0x1, f=0x2, d=0, '99f9a8f', t=1 

[03-08 14:03:59.683 7608:7608 I/ViewRootImpl@d87ccc3[LauncherActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 1

[03-08 14:03:59.683 7608:7608 W/StatusBarController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent return false by intercept 

[03-08 14:03:59.683 7608:7608 W/TaskViewTouchController]
onControllerInterceptTouchEvent, clearState.

[03-08 14:03:59.683 7608:7608 W/BaseDragLayer]
findActiveController return false mTouchDispatchState = 0

[03-08 14:03:59.684 7608:7608 I/FastBitmapDrawable]
animatePress : false  immediate : true invalidate : false

[03-08 14:03:59.685 7608:7608 W/ItemClickHandler]
Icon Clicked

[03-08 14:03:59.685 7608:7608 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - APP_LAUNCH/7608@0, type = -999

[03-08 14:03:59.686 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 28944636  [7608 / 0]    HINT : APP_LAUNCH    list : 

[03-08 14:03:59.686 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPULittleMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 28944636    Value : 1785600

[03-08 14:03:59.687 8404:8404 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - com.sec.android.sdhms/8404@9, type = -999

[03-08 14:03:59.688 1166:7345 I/Pageboost]
stop alp by timeout

[03-08 14:03:59.688 1166:7307 I/ActivityTaskManager]
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[240,298][436,644]} from uid 10159

[03-08 14:03:59.689 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPUMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 28944636    Value : 2841600

[03-08 14:03:59.689 1166:7307 D/ActivityTaskManager]
TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null activity=ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity display-area-from-source=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@127551527 task-display-area=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@127551527 display-area-windowing-mode=1

[03-08 14:03:59.689 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 35393500  [8404 / 9]    HINT : APP_START    list : 

[03-08 14:03:59.689 1166:7307 D/ActivityTaskManager]
TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null activity=ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t-1} display-area-from-source=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@127551527 task-display-area=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@127551527 display-area-windowing-mode=1 inherit-from-source=fullscreen activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) non-freeform-display maximized-bounds

[03-08 14:03:59.689 1166:7258 D/DexPreloader]
create a new DexPreloadTask pkg:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard  path:/data/app/~~f9Wyht3YyDbLgiGTk3VntA==/com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard-50l-Z2i_iAX5EtrGocUa7g==

[03-08 14:03:59.689 1166:7979 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - AMS_APP_SWITCH/1166@36, type = -999

[03-08 14:03:59.689 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPUMaxFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 35393500    Value : 2841600

[03-08 14:03:59.690 7608:7723 I/AppIconSolution]
getThemeIconWithBG called with public API, pkg = com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.690 1166:7979 D/ActivityManagerPerformance]
AMP_acquire() APP_SWITCH

[03-08 14:03:59.690 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 723039  [1166 / 36]    HINT : AMS_APP_SWITCH    list : 

[03-08 14:03:59.690 8020:8020 E/pageboostd]
Received HALT command code 2

[03-08 14:03:59.690 956:1361 I/SurfaceFlinger]
id=17258 createSurf (0x0),-1 flag=24004, Task=151#0

[03-08 14:03:59.691 7608:7723 I/AppIconSolution]
start to load, pkg=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, bg=192-192, dr=192-192, forDefault=true, density=640

[03-08 14:03:59.691 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPULittleMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 723039    Value : 1785600

[03-08 14:03:59.691 7608:7723 I/AppIconSolution]
getIconScale, pkg=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, size=192, iconScale=IconScale[alpha=0, scale=0.72, isCrop=false]

[03-08 14:03:59.691 8404:8404 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - com.sec.android.sdhms/8404@9, type = -999

[03-08 14:03:59.692 1166:7307 D/ActivityTaskManager]
TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=Task{47580a4 #151 visible=false type=standard mode=fullscreen translucent=true A=10295:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard U=0 StackId=151 sz=0} activity=ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t-1} display-from-task=0 task-display-area=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@127551527 display-area-windowing-mode=1 inherit-from-source=fullscreen activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) non-freeform-display maximized-bounds

[03-08 14:03:59.693 956:1576 I/SurfaceFlinger]
id=17259 createSurf (0x0),-1 flag=80004, ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t151}#0

[03-08 14:03:59.694 7608:7723 I/AppIconSolution]
default container[Contain], pkg=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, bg=266-266, dr=192-192

[03-08 14:03:59.694 7608:7723 I/LauncherActivityInfo]
packageName: com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, useThemeIcon: false, height: 266, width: 266, density: 640

[03-08 14:03:59.695 1166:2932 D/DexPreloader]
/data/app/~~f9Wyht3YyDbLgiGTk3VntA==/com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard-50l-Z2i_iAX5EtrGocUa7g==/oat/arm64/base.art is already preloaded

[03-08 14:03:59.695 1166:7307 V/WindowManager]
Prepare app transition: transit=TRANSIT_TASK_OPEN mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_UNSET alwaysKeepCurrent=false displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5809 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked:2595 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityInner:2674 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityUnchecked:2197 

[03-08 14:03:59.695 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPUMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 723039    Value : 2841600

[03-08 14:03:59.695 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 35393500  [8404 / 9]    HINT : APP_START    list : 

[03-08 14:03:59.696 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPUMaxFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 35393500    Value : 2841600

[03-08 14:03:59.697 1166:7307 W/WindowManager]
Execute app transition: mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_TASK_OPEN, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.executeAppTransition:4054 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.resumeFocusedStacksTopActivities:2703 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityInner:2705 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityUnchecked:2197 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest:1607 

[03-08 14:03:59.700 1166:7307 I/SemDvfsHyPerManager]
acquire hyper - AMS_APP_LAUNCH/1166@19, type = -999

[03-08 14:03:59.700 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 702724  [1166 / 19]    HINT : AMS_APP_LAUNCH    list : 

[03-08 14:03:59.700 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPULittleMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 702724    Value : 1785600

[03-08 14:03:59.701 1166:1521 D/StorageManagerService]
getExternalStorageMountMode: uid=10295 packageName=com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.702 1166:1521 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.702 1166:1521 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 135754954; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.702 864:901 I/HYPER-HAL]
[ResourceManager.cpp]updateResource(): [CPUMinFreq] UpdateResource Request ID : 702724    Value : 2841600

[03-08 14:03:59.702 1166:1539 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter]
Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10295; state: DISABLED

[03-08 14:03:59.705 1166:1522 D/InputTransport]
Input channel constructed: 'cf52428', fd=756

[03-08 14:03:59.705 1166:1522 D/InputTransport]
Input channel constructed: 'cf52428', fd=760

[03-08 14:03:59.705 791:791 I/zygote]
Priority USAP Pool refill. New USAPs: 1

[03-08 14:03:59.705 956:1575 I/SurfaceFlinger]
id=17260 createSurf (0x0),-1 flag=80004, cf52428 Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard#0

[03-08 14:03:59.706 1166:1522 I/ViewRootImpl@247a24b[TickTockSoundBoard]]
setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@88c5ad4 TM=true

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 I/DragController]
endDrag

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 W/PageOverlayMover]
updateActivityLifecycleState : 3

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 I/SPayUpdater]
updateSpayHandler launcher activity is paused false

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 I/BlurOperator]
progress = 1.0, mBlurProgress = 1.0, forced = true, mForced = false

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 I/BlurOperator]
mSetTime = 1646766238773, currentTimeMs = 1646766239708

[03-08 14:03:59.708 7608:7608 I/BlurOperator]
blurAmount = 0.125, mBgBlurAmount = 0.125, show = true, mPreBlur = 0.125, mDuration = 1

[03-08 14:03:59.709 2890:2890 I/libc]
SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0

[03-08 14:03:59.709 1166:7430 D/MARsPolicyManager]
onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, userId = 0

[03-08 14:03:59.711 1166:8059 D/MARs:DefaultAppFilter]
filter : com.samsung.android.messaging(0)(SMS)

[03-08 14:03:59.711 1166:8059 D/FreecessController]
com.sec.android.app.myfiles is top app, skip to freeze

[03-08 14:03:59.712 8809:8981 I/PageOverlayServiceImpl]
[FROM HOME] updateActivityLifecycleState : 3

[03-08 14:03:59.714 791:791 D/Zygote]
Forked child process 2935

[03-08 14:03:59.719 2890:2890 E/kTockSoundBoar]
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.

[03-08 14:03:59.721 2890:2890 D/ActivityThread]
setConscryptValidator

[03-08 14:03:59.722 2890:2890 D/ActivityThread]
setConscryptValidator - put

[03-08 14:03:59.721 1166:1522 D/ViewRootImpl@247a24b[TickTockSoundBoard]]
controlInsetsForCompatibility: hideByFlags=0x1, showByFlags=0x0, flags=0x81830518, sysUiVis=0x0, matchParent=true, nonAttachedAppWindow=true

[03-08 14:03:59.722 1166:1522 D/InsetsSourceConsumer]
setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=0, host=Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:236 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1172 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1049 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417 android.view.InsetsController.hide:984 android.view.InsetsController.hide:967 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:2852 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3314 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:8059 D/FreecessController]
com.dp.logcatapp is top app, skip to freeze

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:7430 V/WindowManager]
Prepare app transition: transit=TRANSIT_TASK_OPEN mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_UNSET alwaysKeepCurrent=false displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5809 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked:2255 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked:1873 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.resumeFocusedStacksTopActivities:2678 

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:1166 I/Pageboost]
package com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:1166 I/Pageboost]
stop alp

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:7345 I/Pageboost]
Record App IO : com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard pid 0

[03-08 14:03:59.731 1166:7430 W/WindowManager]
Execute app transition: mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_TASK_OPEN, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.executeAppTransition:4054 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.resumeFocusedStacksTopActivities:2703 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked:1555 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityPaused:5765 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.activityPaused:2562 

[03-08 14:03:59.732 1166:1539 I/ActivityManager]
Start proc 2890:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/u0a295 for pre-top-activity {com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}

[03-08 14:03:59.734 1166:1522 V/WindowManager]
Relayout Window{cf52428 u0 Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x2280

[03-08 14:03:59.735 1166:1522 D/WindowManager]
isScreenshotDisabledLocked - win: Window{cf52428 u0 Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard}

[03-08 14:03:59.735 1166:1522 D/WindowManager]
isScreenshotDisabledLocked: userId = 0, disabled =false

[03-08 14:03:59.735 956:1361 I/SurfaceFlinger]
id=17261 createSurf (1080x2172),1 flag=404, Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard#0

[03-08 14:03:59.735 1166:1522 D/WindowManager]
makeSurface duration=1 name=Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 V/WindowManager]
Changing focus from Window{99f9a8f u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:567 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6311 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2713 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:219 

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 D/StatusBarManagerService]
notifyRequestedSystemKey recent=false home=false

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 V/WindowManager]
rotationForOrientation(orient=SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT (1), last=ROTATION_0 (0)); user=ROTATION_0 (0) USER_ROTATION_LOCKED

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 D/WindowManager]
rotationForOrientation, orientationSource=ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t151}

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 V/WindowOrientationListener]
getProposedRotation: -1

[03-08 14:03:59.736 1166:1522 V/WindowManager]
Computed rotation=ROTATION_0 (0) for display id=0 based on lastOrientation=SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT (1) and oldRotation=ROTATION_0 (0), caller=com.android.server.wm.DisplayRotation.updateOrientation:394 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.updateOrientation:1698 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.updateOrientation:1603 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2742 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:219 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 

[03-08 14:03:59.737 1166:9322 I/ActivityManager]
DSS OFF for com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard

[03-08 14:03:59.737 1166:1522 V/WindowManager]
Relayout hash=cf52428, pid=1166: mAttrs={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=pan} ty=APPLICATION_STARTING wanim=0x1030304
  fl=81830518
  pfl=12020011
  apr=LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS
  bhv=SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  fitSides= naviIconColor=0
  sfl=100000}

[03-08 14:03:59.737 1166:1522 I/ViewRootImpl@247a24b[TickTockSoundBoard]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,108,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)0 dur=15 res=0x7 s={true -5476376672537300336} ch=true fn=-1

[03-08 14:03:59.738 1166:7430 V/WindowManager]
Relayout Window{99f9a8f u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x2280

[03-08 14:03:59.744 1166:1522 D/WindowManager]
finishDrawingWindow: Window{cf52428 u0 Splash Screen com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING

[03-08 14:03:59.744 1166:7430 V/WindowManager]
Relayout hash=99f9a8f, pid=7608: mAttrs={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=nothing} layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=shortEdges ty=BASE_APPLICATION fmt=TRANSPARENT wanim=0x10302f2
  fl=81910102
  pfl=16020000
  vsysui=1700
  bhv=SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  fitSides= dimAmount=0.125 dimDuration=1 naviIconColor=0
  sfl=40}

[03-08 14:03:59.744 1166:7430 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376676829868816]

[03-08 14:03:59.744 1166:7430 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376676829868816]

[03-08 14:03:59.745 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376676831896160]

[03-08 14:03:59.745 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376676831896160]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 1166:9322 D/ActivityManager]
attachApplicationLocked() app=ProcessRecord{73881c2 2890:com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/u0a295} app.isolatedEntryPoint=null instr2=null

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x30aaba5 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376676831649936]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376676831649936]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376676831405120]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376676831405120]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376676831652576]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/SurfaceControl]
nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376676831652576]

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/ViewRootImpl@d87ccc3[LauncherActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)0 dur=12 res=0x1 s={true -5476376672536131856} ch=false fn=275

[03-08 14:03:59.746 7608:7608 I/BlurUtils]
blurByWindowManager with show = true, dest = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@e308057, amount = 0.125, duration = 1, sBlur=true

[03-08 14:03:59.747 1166:9322 V/WindowManager]
rotationForOrientation(orient=SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT (1), last=ROTATION_0 (0)); user=ROTATION_0 (0) USER_ROTATION_LOCKED

[03-08 14:03:59.747 1166:9322 D/WindowManager]
rotationForOrientation, orientationSource=ActivityRecord{a6df337 u0 com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t151}

[03-08 14:03:59.747 1166:9322 V/WindowOrientationListener]
getProposedRotation: -1

[03-08 14:03:59.747 1166:9322 V/WindowManager]
Computed rotation=ROTATION_0 (0) for display id=0 based on lastOrientation=SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT (1) and oldRotation=ROTATION_0 (0), caller=com.android.server.wm.DisplayRotation.updateOrientation:394 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.updateOrientation:1698
```

Comment: investigate this one:
`Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:579 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:443 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:12392 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash:12327`

Comment: and investigate this one: `[03-08 14:03:59.635 2847:2847 E/AndroidRuntime]
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard, PID: 2847 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:`

Comment: So what I can see at a first glance is that you have some big problem in something called `com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard` (maybe that can tell you something, perhaps remove that package?). You also seem to have some kind of permission problem (`without a qualified user`) concerning `com.android.server` so that package might be troublesome as well. But the first one seems to use it. I would definitely try to remove that soundboard package.

Comment: com.ShadowZ.TickTockSoundBoard is my android app, it just keeps crashing after I added the Google Admob Script in and put banner ads on my app. I removed the ads and its still giving me the same error in the logcat :(

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786963/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-android-gms-ads-mobileadsinitprovider-java-la